# Do inequalities hold under differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

If I have the inequality $f \leq g$, does this imply $f'\leq g'$?

The reason I am asking is because I am using this fact to prove a question with Taylor theorem.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, does $a \le b, \,c \le d$ imply $a-c \le b-d\,$?

Comment: Can you think of a increasing function whose graph is under the x-axis? Yes, you can (just take any bounded increasing function and apply a translation). So, the answer is no because your questions  is equivalent to "is a function which attains only non-positive values necessarily non-increasing?" (see my post for details).

Comment: It really scares me that you're learning about Taylor series but haven't even given any indication that you understand what the question is asking. Did you understand the question at least? If so, what examples did you try? If not -- and apologies if this sounds rude -- I'm honestly worried you're not in the correct math class for your level to begin with. In that case you might want to either switch classes or spend a while reviewing prerequisites before continuing...

Comment: @Mehrdad  I just got confused a bit. Its 5 am here and I am not in my best mental state right now. Think its about time to sleep for me.

Comment: @AspiringMat: Oh... please prioritize sleep higher in your life :( it does wonders...

Comment: No, but inequalities are preserved under *integration* over a positive directed interval, for example $x \leq e^x \implies \int_0^x x'{\rm d}x' \leq \int_0^x e^{x'}{\rm d}x'$ or $\frac{x^2}{2} \leq e^x-1$ for $x>0$.

Comment: It's easier to reason on $h:=f-g$. Does $h\le0$ imply $h'\le 0$ ? Of course no, a negative function can be increasing or decreasing. But a Winther said, the converse holds: a negative, decreasing function remains negative.

Comment: @Mehrdad Strange things frighten you.  Let's avoid being condescending with people trying to learn.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: The point of my comment was not to be condescending; it to suggest that it might be worth checking that you ("you" as in the OP) are in the right math class, since otherwise you don't learn much and it wastes your own time. I couldn't figure out how to make that sound nice, so like I said, apologies if it wasn't, but it seemed very much worth pointing out.

Comment: @Mehrdad I understood what you meant.  You could have tried harder to make it not be condescending.  Nonetheless, diagnosing someone as being in the wrong placement based on one offhand question is really a nasty thing to do that's just going to--at best--discourage someone from asking questions (on a Q and A site) and at worst keep an otherwise worthy candidate from pursuing mathematics.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: *"You could have tried harder to make it not be condescending."* Uhm, I spent over 20 minutes (probably more like 30) writing that comment. Maybe you could lead by example instead of accusing me of doing what you're currently doing? The thing about the diagnosis is fair and I'll try to keep that in mind, but I'm not sure the whole site is in agreement with you regarding whether we should be encouraging or discouraging questions like this -- SE expects "what have you tried?" to be answered in the question, so many (not me) would argue this question should have been closed.

Comment: @Mehrdad Rule of thumb is that if you can't say something without being condescending, maybe don't say it.  Have a good one.

Comment: If it were the case, then any bounded real differentiable function would be constant : $-M \leq f(x) \leq M$ implies $0 \leq f'(x) \leq 0$, so $f$ is constant on $\Bbb R$... !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Consider $x^2\leq x $ in $[0,1]$. Does that imply that $2x\leq 1$ for all x in $[0,1] $? ( A counterexample ).

Note you can never differentiate with an inequality. Instead, the general idea for checking inequalities with differentiation is that we take $h (x)=f (x)-g (x) $ and then try the derivative test to see whether function is increasing or decreasing. That way, if the inequality $h(a) \geq 0$ holds at a particular point a, we can prove it holds for all $x \geq a$ if $h$ is increasing and for all $x \leq a$ if $h$ is decreasing.

Comment: does not imply?

Comment: No I wanted to make it rhetorical.

Comment: Thank you. It's 5 am here and I was really confused. Don't even know why i asked this question in the first place

Comment: No problem we are humans!

Answer (score 15):

Your question is equivalent to *is a function which attains only non-positive values necessarily non-increasing?* So, the answer is **no** because there exist increasing functions whose graphs are under the $x$-axis:

[image]

(As a general remark, the rates of change of a function has "nothing" to do with the image of the function in the sense that: (i) given a set $X$, we can find functions having $X$ as image and different rates of change; (ii) given a function, there are other functions having the same rates of change and different images.)

**Details:** As differentiation is linear, the question

> Does $f\leq g$ imply $f'\leq g'$?

is the same as

> Does $h\leq 0$ imply $h'\leq 0$?

which can be rewritten as

> Is a function which attains only non-positive values necessarily non-increasing?

From this point of view, the answer becomes clear: No because there are (a lot of) increasing functions whose graphs are under the $x$-axis (take any bounded increasing function and apply a translation). Probably, the simplest example is a line segment (see picture above).

Comment: +1 But I wouldn't say that it has *nothing* to do with the image of the function though

Comment: I would go with $0 \leq h$ and $0 \leq h'$, and a decreasing positive function. The first quadrant is the most usual... :-)

Comment: @Ant I've edited that sentence to make clear my point.

Comment: @PabloH The setting you suggest is indeed good. It is simpler in the sense that we do not even need to think in translations. My setting is a consequence of the habit of isolating things at left when dealing with algebraic expressions.

Comment: It took me a second, but I thought of a function that converges at a limit as an example of a n always-increasing function that never achieves a positive value.

Answer (score 9):

Take two functions whose derivative have whatever inequality you wish (ie., $f^\prime > g^\prime$ or vice versa). Then just add or subtract a constant to one of the functions to make it larger or smaller than the other.

In short, you can very easily create pairs of functions whose values obey one inequality relation and their derivatives hold another.  Or the same.