# For $f(x) = ax^2 -2 + {1\over x}$, find the smallest $a$ such that $\{\forall x \gt 0: f(x) \ge 0\}$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)= ax^2 -2 + {1\over x}$, where $a$ is a real constant.

The smallest $a$ for which $f(x)$ is greater than or equal to zero for all $x$ greater than zero is:

1. $2^2\over3^3$
2. $2^3\over 3^3$
3. $2^4\over 3^3$
4. $2^5\over 3^3$

Can anybody please solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\leq0$ our expression can be negative.

Let $a>0$.

Thus, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$ax^2+\frac{1}{x}-2=ax^2+2\cdot\frac{1}{2x}-2\geq3\sqrt[3]{ax^2\left(\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2}-2=3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{4}}-2.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes. I can finish it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Alma You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to solve a cubic inequality. There is a general method to solve this which is Cardano's method. You could also use [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Vieta's_substitution) substitution.

We know $x \ge 0$ so we can multiply by $x$:

$$
ax^2 - 2 + {1\over x} \ge 0 \iff \\
\iff ax^3-2x+1 \ge0
$$

Now reduce to [depressed cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic):

$$
t^3 + pt + q \ge0 \\
p = -{2 \over a} \\
q = {1\over a}
$$

Now use Vieta's substitution:

$$
x = w + {2\over 3aw}
$$

Now substitute $x$:

$$
w^3 + {8\over 27a^3w^3} + {1\over a}\ge 0
$$

Multiply by $w^3$:

$$
w^6 + {w^3\over a} + {8 \over 27a^3}  \ge 0
$$

Make another substitution $w^3 = z$:

$$
z^2 + {z \over a} + {8\over 27a^3} \ge0
$$

Find discriminant:

$$
D = {1\over a^2} - {32\over 27a^3}
$$

We want it to be less or equal to $0$:
$$
{1\over a^2} - {32\over 27a^3} \le0
$$

Hence:
$$
1 \le{32 \over 27a} \iff a\le {32\over 27} = {2^5\over 3^3}
$$

Comment: The last option is 2^5/3^3.

Comment: @Alma well, I've looked at the graph and indeed $a = {2^5 \over 3^3}$. Can't spot an error in my solution

Comment: @Alma, I've found an error, fixed the answer.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @roman. Also can you please take a look at my answer and check if the method is correct? I have suggested an alternate method but i'm not really sure if it's correct

Comment: @Alma, $a \ge \left({2\over x^2} - {1\over x^3}\right)$. If we find a derivative: $-{4\over x^3} + {3\over x^4} \le 0 \implies x \ge {3\over 4}$. Now if we plug that value in the initial equation you can show that $a \ge {32\over 27}$. But i'm not sure that will work in general case. You may wan't to try and prove it, or ask another question on this site.

Comment: why will the derivative be <=0?

Comment: @Alma, I meant $f'(x) = 0$. Also note that [inequalities do not hold under differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294397/do-inequalities-hold-under-differentiation)

Comment: Ok. Thank you @roman

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it like this:
Since f(x) >=0, we derive a as a function of f(x) i.e. a >= an expression of x. Then we differentiate this expression and find the value of x at which there is a maxima i.e. a maxima in the graph of a vs x. Then we put that value of x in the expression of a. Shouldn't this value of a be the least value for which f(x) >=0?