# Inequality stays after taking derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, inequality

I have the following inequality:
$$s^k - f(s) \leq 0$$
where $-1 < s \leq 1$ & $k \in R_+$ & $f(s) > 0$. In such case, I am wondering if the following statement also valid: That is, is it right that the sign remains even after taking derivatives?
$$k s^{k-1} \leq f'(s) $$

If not, then will it be valid if $ 0 < s \leq 1$?

I think this is right, but I am wondering how to start the proof.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can easily get a counter example with a constant function $f$.

Comment: Hi @MartinR Thank you for the quick comment!
I have already seen the post that you suggested, but I had remaining questions, so I decided to post a new question. 

The remaining questions are:
(1) Does that mean that there is NO WAY to check the inequality after taking derivatives?
(2) In the post that you suggested, someone mentioned "Take derivatives a function h(x) = f(x) - g(x)." If h'(x) is positive at certain point of x, say t, then is it right to say that f '(t) > g ' (t) ??

Comment: The referenced Q&A clearly shows that nothing can be said about the derivatives. As I suggested, $f(s) = 10$ is a clear counterexample in your case. – If you are referring to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2294400/42969, that is about conclusions in the opposite direction (from the derivatives to the functions).

Comment: For the converse, you may be interested in the racetrack principle